# Drupal Shibboleth attribute mapping

Tags: drupal-7, shibboleth

We are using Shibboleth authentication and it works great. However, the customer wants us to map an attribute to a Drupal role.
This is the attribute they are passing to us: name="urn:oid:2.5.4.19"
friendlyName="somelocation"

We have added the mappings to roles here:

https://someurl/admin/config/people/shib_auth/rules
for both "urn:oid.2.5.4.19" and "somelocation"

In attribute-map.xml, we added:

Yet when users are logging in, they are not being assigned to the right role. Looking at GuacD.log it says:
INFO Shibboleth.AttributeExtractor.XML [42]: skipping unmapped SAML 2.0 Attribute with Name: urn:oid:2.5.4.19

Are we missing anything? Do we need to do anything with attributepolicy.xml?

Thanks!
Antony